# The app references non-public selectors in Payload Capacitor.Framework STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.50

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, capacitor, non-public-selectors

Today, I ran into a problem while trying to upload my capacitor app to the App Store. The app was published a few days ago and, to my understanding, nothing critical for the upload was not changed. The error I receive also does not shed any lights on the actual problem.

The error looks the following:
[image]

And says:

> The app references non-public selectors in Payload/App.app/Frameworks/Capacitor.Framework/Capacitor: applicationNameForUserAgent, initWithFrame:configuration:, isMainFrame, setNavigationDelegate:, targetFrame With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.50 for id (some guid).

I tried numerous approaches, like regenerating the Certificates and the Provisioning Profile. Nothing helps, and this error blocks the publishing of the app. Looks like something internal to Capacitor, but I can't figure what exactly and what specifically has happened in a couple of days from the last successful app publish.

Any help?

Comment: Could you share your Info.plist, I am getting the same error.

Comment: It seems like this is some new global issue, based on some conflict between Ionic Capacitor and Apple: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5661

Comment: any work around for the issue?

Comment: same issue with another package
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/App.app/Frameworks/JitsiMeetSDK.framework/JitsiMeetSDK: estimatedProgress, evaluateScript:, initWithFrame:configuration:, isMainFrame, isPassthrough, navigationType, onSuccess:, removeValuesForKeys:completion:, setNavigationDelegate:, setProcessPool:, showLoading, targetFrame, userContentController, websiteDataStore With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.50 for id 8e37a28d-2947-4056-9434-517d84f568cf

Comment: I assume you mean, "nothing critical for the upload was changed"? Currently, it says "nothing critical for the upload was **not** changed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential workaround until it will be officially fixed:

I searched the resulting code by Ionic build for `applicationNameForUserAgent` and `isMainFrame`—other strings did not match anything—and found one instance for `isMainFrame` (line 107 was found) in `WebViewDelegationHandler` and three instances of `applicationNameForUserAgent` in `CAPBridgeViewController` (lines 115-120) (all searches in the xCode workspace). I removed all of these lines and the build was magically published.

I found on StackOverflow some thread from 2019 that also blamed (then) `cordova-web-view-plugin`.

I'm not sure about how bad it is to remove those lines of code, yet at least it offers some sort of a solution, if at all.

I tested on my app and did not observe any flaws.

Answer (score 6):

I'm having this now in Xcode 14.

This is a bug on Apple's backend validation.

However I was able to distribute without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the warning as well, but the build is successfully uploaded of TF.
If not you can give it a second try.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32915750)

Comment: its help @saad Sheikh

Comment: Agree, these kind of comments are not helping but just pollute the page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if removing or renaming the references is a safe option. Good for you if it works. The reality is it may be an Apple issue. Sounds weird, but it look like it is. I have the same issue on Capacitor but right now it happens to all Cross-platform community:

- Capacitor: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5661
- Flutter: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105472
- React Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33789

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug on Apple’s backend, it’s fixed now according to one of their engineers

> The issue has been resolved on the app validation backend. Please try resubmitting. Sorry for the trouble.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127678?answerId=715975022#715975022

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, with updating xcode and ios 16. I solved it by setting the "Minimum Deployments" in Targets > General, to the lowest value available.

I was able to distribute with a warning but doing this removed that too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-native and faced the same issue, with updating xcode and ios 16.

I solved it by setting the **"Minimum Deployments" in Targets > General**, to the lowest value available that is **11**.

Answer (score 0):

I can submit the app using Transporter.
Archive and export app using Xcode and deliver app using Transporter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the things above and none of it worked. Refer to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31507#issuecomment-1043292372) GitHub issue for the working answer. Follow the steps as he said or simple copy this piece of code in you `Podfile`.

```
def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end

post_install do |installer|
        find_and_replace("./node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTKeyCommands.m",
                                "_modifierFlags",
                                "_modifierEventFlags")
        find_and_replace("./node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTKeyCommands.m",
                                "_modifiedInput",
                                "_modifiedEventInput")
        find_and_replace("./node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTKeyCommands.m",
                                "_isKeyDown",
                                "_isKeyEventDown")
        find_and_replace("./node_modules/react-native/React/DevSupport/RCTPackagerClient.h",
                                "handleNotification",
                                "handlePackageNotification")

        find_and_replace("./node_modules/react-native/React/DevSupport/RCTPackagerConnection.mm",
                                "handleNotification",
                                "handlePackageNotification")
    end
```

Make sure that you first find this function and replace it `post_install do |installer|`